# How to write nginx rewrite rule for replacing query param in query string

Tags: nginx

folks!

We have following http request:

`http://example.com/foo?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fbar`

We want to replace `redirect_uri` from "example.com" to "example.net".

How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it like this

```
location /foo {
   if ($args ~* "(.*)(example\.com)(.*)") {
       set $args "$1example.net$3";
       return 301 $scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me, but only after I added a try_files statement under the if-block to process the new URI. The location string matches both!

Comment: Missing a `?`  between `$uri` and `$args` should be `return 301 $scheme://$host$uri?$args;`